# Допустимо ли называть арбуз ягодой?

Tags: лексика

Вопрос не совсем по русскому языку,  некоторое отношение имеет.

Часто слышу, что арбуз - это ягода, хотя его плод тыквина (как огурец или дыня) и в бытовом плане на ягоду он не похож.

Можно ли арбуз назвать ягодой и если нет,  то почему называют?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как-то тоже задавался этим вопросом в связи с одной интеллектуальной онлайн-игрой. В общем, вот краткие выводы из дискуссии:

1. Современные биологические классификации считают недопустимым называть плод арбуза ягодой, только **тыквиной**.
2. Тыквина - это ягодообразный плод, мало отличающийся от плода ягоды по строению, но имеющий другой способ образования.
3. На школьном уровне особых различий между ягодой, тыквиной и померанцем не делают.
4. Сложность состоит в том, что есть подгруппы **ягодовые плоды** (fructus baccati) делятся на **Ягоды** (bacca), Тыквины (pepo), гесперидии (hesperidium), гранатины (balausta).

Поэтому и допустимость называть арбуз ягодой будет зависеть от перевода с латинского фразы **fructus baccati**, если перевести как *плоды ягод*, то можно, если ягодовые, или ягодные, плоды, то не совсем. В общем, если не хотите спора на биологическую тему, биологу-классификатору говорить, что арбуз - ягода не стоит, но и особой ошибки в этом нет.

Answer (score 7):

Так, похоже, тут нужна консультация биолога, то есть, меня))
Так вот, арбуз — это ягода. Классическая ягода чисто в ботаническом понимании этого слова.
Так что называть его так вполне допустимо. Другое дело, что как-то не очень принято, потому что есть стереотип, что ягода должна быть маленькой.

Comment: Ну так дикий арбуз размером от крупной сливы до теннисного мячика.    
Хотя вообще-то там был еще один вопрос, насчет того, можно ли считать плод, именуемый строго ложной ягодой, просто ягодой.

Answer (score 2):

Не про арбуз, но в тему:

– Русский язык довольно свободно обращается с биологической классификацией. Любой носитель русского языка твердо знает, что помидор – это овощ, хотя с биологической точки зрения он ничем не отличается от смородины. Точно так же все, что выращивают дома в горшках, называется «цветами». Поэтому, если сказать «Увидишь на подоконнике цветок – уходи», носитель русского языка поймет, что явка провалена, даже если в горшке будет пальма.

Лингвист Алексей Шмелев

Answer (score 0):

Да. Вполне справедливо называют. 
Я уже писал в другом ответе, что биологически большинство бахчевых  - ягоды. 
В основы классификации положено развитие плода непосредственно из завязи (или завязи и близлежащих элементов - т.н. ложная ягода), а также наличие кожистой оболочки, внешнего и внутреннего внеплодника и многоплодия (впрочем, тут есть исключения - кизил, например).
Арбуз, тыква и дыня вполне удовлетворяют всем этим критериям.

А вот огурец а кабачки - лишь отчасти, ибо плод формируется не из цветка, собственно цветок просто завядает, его остатки иногда можно наблюдать у молодых огурчиков даже в магазине. Поэтому огурцы - ближе к обычным фруктам.

Comment: То что огурец дыня и арбуз имеют один и тот же тип плода Вы можете прочитать в любом ботаническом справочнике. И плод этот называют максимум "ягодообразным" или "ложной ягодой", что тоже не ягода, о чём как раз и говорит слово "ложный". Так почему тогда называть так можно?

Кизил как и вишня - костянки, а не ягоды с биологической точки зрения.

Comment: Одинаковый тип плода имеют арбуз, дыня и тыква. Огурец - нет. Во всяком случае так считалось в годы моего ученичества. 
А "ложной ягодой"  - правильно называть даже клубнику. Это не мешает считать её ягодой.  

Впрочем, я не биолог. Могу что-то и попутать в деталях.  

Важнее вот что:

>Тыквина представляет собой паракарпный многосемянный плод... [b][i]Морфологически родственна ягоде[/i][/b], но отличается от неё большим количеством семян и структурой околоплодника...    
  
(Вики)  

По мне так вполне достаточно, чтобы на бытовом уровне считать арбуз ягодой.

Comment: Так потому и ложные, что не ягоды, а лишь похожи.

Comment: Нет, не поэтому. Писал же. Ягода "чистая" образуется их цветка, а ложная ягода - из цветка и близлежащих элементов (обычно - цветоложа), а истинные плоды - (орешки-семечки) расположены на поверхности или внутри. Так что дело не в похожести.